# Does an eigenvector of corresponding eigenvalue '1' have to be a stochastic vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

I was going through Markov chains where all the state vectors are stochastic (their entries add up to 1). Then, since a steady state vector in a Markov chain is both stochastic and also an eigenvector with a corresponding eigenvalue of 1, I was wondering whether all eigenvectors of corresponding eigenvalue 1, have to be stochastic vectors.

Comment: $(-1,-1,...,-1)$ is also an eigen vector corresponding to eigen value $1$.

Comment: Any non-zero multiple of an eigenvector is again an eigenvector.